# cdef statement not allowed here for structure

Tags: cython

I have a simple Astruct.pyx with a struct definition (Astruct.pxd):

```
cdef struct A:
    int x
    int y
    int z
```

And a Cython function, that uses it (struct_test.pyx):

```
from random import randint
from Astruct cimport A

def do():
    N = 1000000
    M = 65535
    As = []
    total = 0
    for i in xrange(N):
        cdef A a
        a.x = randint(0, M)
        a.y = randint(0, M)
        a.z = randint(0, M)
        As.append(a)
    for i in xrange(N):
        total += As[i].x + As[i].y + As[i].z
    print total
```

However, when I try to build struct_test.pyx, I get this error: "cdef statement not allowed here", pointing at "cdef A a". It does not complain about another definition of A variable if it is outside the loop, but I do not understand what is so special about for loop.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Python and C have different scoping rules. Cython uses the same scoping rules as Python so variables "declared" (first assigned) inside of a `for`/`if`/`while` or other block are in scope for the whole function. This is also true for variables declared using `cdef`, but as you've seen these variable must be declared at the function level and not in a sub-block.

I can think of at least two good reasons to have this requirement:

- It's more clear:  Users coming into Cython with a C background will not be surprised when their variables don't have the scope that they might expect.
- It means that the C code generated by Cython more closely tracks the original Cython code, which, I'm sure, makes for easier debugging and implementation for the Cython developers.

Comment: For more discussion and examples, see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/iNmemRwUyuU).